# How to iterate over yml sections with structs?

Tags: go, viper-go

I use viper. I'm trying to get info from structs with yml-config.

```
type Config struct {
    Account       User           `mapstructure:"user"`      
}

type User struct {
    Name       string           `mapstructure:"name"`
    Contacts   []Contact        `mapstructure:"contact"`
}

type Contact struct {
    Type          string          `mapstructure:"type"`
    Value         string          `mapstructure:"value"`
}

func Init() *Config {
    conf := new(Config)

    viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
    viper.ReadInConfig()
    ...
    viper.Unmarshal(conf)
    return conf
}

...
config := Init()
...
for _, contact := range config.Account.Contacts {
   type := contact.type
   vlaue := contact.value
}
```

And config.yml

```
user:
  name: John
  contacts:
    email:
      type: email
      value: test@test.com
    skype:
      type: skype
      value: skypeacc
```

Can I get structure items like this? I could not get contact data like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only significant problem is that in your data structures you've declared `Contacts` as a list, but in your YAML file it's a dictionary. If you structure your input file like this:

```
user:
  name: John
  contacts:
    - type: email
      value: test@test.com
    - type: skype
      value: skypeacc
```

Then you can read it like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Config struct {
    User User
}

type User struct {
    Name     string
    Contacts []Contact
}

type Contact struct {
    Type  string
    Value string
}

func main() {
    var cfg Config

    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    viper.Unmarshal(&cfg)
    fmt.Println("user: ", cfg.User.Name)
    for _, contact := range cfg.User.Contacts {
        fmt.Println("  ", contact.Type, ": ", contact.Value)
    }
}
```

The above code is runnable as-is; you should just be able to drop it
into a file and build it.  When I run the above example, I get as
output:

```
user:  John
   email :  test@test.com
   skype :  skypeacc
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting right what you want to achieve, and based on the `for` loop you provided;

- What you actually need is a YAML **sequence**, which is an **array**. So your final YAML file should look like;

```yaml
user:
  name: John
  contacts:
      - type: email
        value: test@test.com
      - type: skype
        value: skypeacc
      - type: email
        value: joe@example.com
```

- Also, you have a typo in your tag on `Contacts` slice. It should match the  YAML key;

```golang
type User struct {
   Name     string    `mapstructure:"name"`
   Contacts []Contact `mapstructure:"contacts"`
}
```

If you wish to keep the original YAML file structure you have to provide a tag (and the corresponding struct field) for each YAML key, so looping over it wouldn't be possible out of the box, because `email` and `skype` are parsed as struct fields. An example of the struct for the original YAML file would be;

```golang
type Config struct {
    Account User `mapstructure:"user"`
}

type User struct {
    Name     string   `mapstructure:"name"`
    Contacts Contacts `mapstructure:"contacts"`
}

type Contacts struct {
    Email Contact `mapstructure:"email"`
    Skype Contact `mapstructure:"skype"`
}

type Contact struct {
    Type  string `mapstructure:"type"`
    Value string `mapstructure:"value"`
}
```